# SQLite date split

Tags: sqlite, date, split

In SQLite, I have a 'date' field that's varchar(20), as an example dates currently read '12-AUG-15'. I need to split the date field into 4 separate fields: 'day', 'month', 'year', and 'month_num'. Problem is I don't know how to convert month names into numbers as well as the year into a 4 digit year. I'm thinking of using case and string concatenation functions? Any advice how to start it is well appreciated.

Comment: SQLite doesn't honor `varchar` limits. [`varchar(20)` is just `text`](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html). In general don't use size limits in your table without a very good reason. It's not saving any space. It's hard coding business logic in the data schema.

Comment: I've changed my answer to show how you can do this with a user defined SQLite function.

Answer (score 3):

SQLite has very limited [date](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) and string functions. The date functions understand [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iso8601). You're better off in the long run converting to ISO 8601 and then using the date functions. It will sort better, and most everything understands ISO 8601 format.

SQLite doesn't have an easy way to do this, but you can write a user defined function to do the conversion. Most SQLite drivers allow you to write it in whatever language you're using. Here's an example in Ruby.

```
require "sqlite3"
require "date"

# Open a database
db = SQLite3::Database.new "test.db"

# Create a SQLite function date_to_iso()
db.create_function( "date_to_iso", 1 ) do |proxy, date|
  # Convert 12-AUG-15 to 2015-08-12 (ISO 8601 format)
  iso = Date.strptime(date, "%d-%b-%y");

  # This is how you return the result via a FunctionProxy
  proxy.result = iso.to_s
end

# Now you can use date_iso_iso() in SQLite queries in this process.
db.execute("UPDATE stuff SET date = date_to_iso(date)")
```

Then you can use `strftime` to query the individual date parts.

```
select
    strftime("%d", date) as day,
    strftime("%m", month) as month,
    strftime("%Y", year) as year
from whatever;
```

Unfortunately, SQLite doesn't have a way to convert to the month name. You could write a big CASE statement.

```
select case strftime("%m", month)
           when 1 then 'JAN'
           when 2 then 'FEB'
           ...
       end
 from whatever;
```

Or you could add another user defined function to do the conversion.

But since you now have a standard date format, it's probably better to just return the whole ISO 8601 date and let the application do what it wants with it.